# Телеграм-бот - кнопка "Добавить в корзину "

Tags: python, telebot

У меня не выходит кнопку добавить под этой инфой товара

в utils.py я написала этот код

```
def generate_add_to_card_button(product_id):

    button = {"inline_keyboard": []}
    products = database.get_products_from_one_category(product_id) 
    for i in products:
        button['inline_keyboard'].append([{
            'text': "Добавить",
            'callback_data': "add_to_card"
        }])
    return button
```

этот код в bot.py

```
    elif "products" in data:
                    product_id = data.split("_")[2]
                    await self.bot.send_message(text=utils.generate_add_to_card_button(product_id), chat_id=chat_id)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный* код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

в функции `generate_add_to_card_button()` сериализуйте `button` в строку JSON-формата:

```
import json
...


def generate_add_to_card_button():
    products = ['asd']
    button = {"inline_keyboard": []}
    for _ in products:
        button['inline_keyboard'].append([{
            'text': "Добавить",
            'callback_data': "add_to_card"
        }])
    return json.dumps(button)
```

Вопрос только как вы поймёте, что именно было добавлено в корзину, ведь `callback_data` не содержит информации о товаре.

Можно воспользоваться следующим кодом для передачи дополнительных данных:

```
{"inline_keyboard":
[[{"text": "Утвердить",
"callback_data": "['order_true', '123']"},
{"text": "Отклонить",
"callback_data": "['order_false', '456']"}]]}

import ast
...

if call.data.startswith("['order_true'"):
        number = ast.literal_eval(call.data)[1]
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                              text='{0}\n{1}'.format(call.message.text, number))
```

Таким образом в сообщении `number` будет 123.

*Только не забывайте про ограничение на `callback_data` в 64 байта.*

Так же можете рассмотреть вариант со [встроенным функционалом приёма платежей](https://core.telegram.org/bots/payments).

[Демо магазин в Telegram](https://t.me/shopbot).